# JOptionPane in struts?

Tags: java, swing, jakarta-ee, struts, joptionpane

I am using below code to display dialog box:

```
if(query.contains(tab)) {         
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Owner does not have privileges to access given table");         
}
```

But I guess `JOptionPane` wont work in struts. So how to display dialog box in struts?

Can I use `JOptionPane` in struts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can't use `JOptionPane` in Struts. Struts runs at server-side. `JOptionPane` would display a Swing dialog on the web server screen, not in the client's browser.

To display a dialog box in a browser, you need JavaScript. You could use [jQuery-UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) for example.

Comment: how can i transfer control to javascript from action class?.like in the above code if condition is true then go to javascript function.

Comment: You forward to a JSP which generates HTML which contain JavaScript code which opens a dialog box as soon as the page is loaded in the browser.